# r retain the recent(id) and impute for NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, imputation

I have a dataset where each row represents a student response. Each column represents a teacher evaluation question.

```
   StudentId     Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4    SystemTime
   1             NA    5    2    NA    09:01:07.2123
   2             1     4    4    NA    09:03:01.3145
   2             NA    4    4    1     09:03:02.6145
   3             1     3    NA   2     09:47:17.6541
   3             1     NA   NA   5     10:01:17.2343
   3             3     NA   1    NA    10:12:01.3435
   4             NA    NA   1    2     12:07:13.1187
```

My goal is to 1) Retain the latest student response which I am doing by

```
df %>% 
  group_by(StudentId) %>%
  slice(which.max(hms(df $SystemTime)))

   StudentId     Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4    SystemTime
   1             NA    5    2    NA    09:01:07.2123
   2             NA    4    4    1     09:03:02.6145
   3             3     NA   1    NA    10:12:01.3435
   4             NA    NA   1    2     12:07:13.1187
```

I also want to impute the missing data in the most recent response based on that students (StudentID) previous response. The final expected result is as shown below

```
  StudentId      Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4    SystemTime
   1             NA    5    2    NA    09:01:07.2123
   2              1    4    4    1     09:03:02.6145
   3              3    3    1    5     10:12:01.3435
   4             NA    NA   1    2     12:07:13.1187
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `fill` `NA` values by group and then select row with most recent value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(StudentId) %>%
  fill(starts_with('Q')) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.POSIXct(SystemTime, format = '%H:%M:%S')))


#  StudentId    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4 SystemTime   
#      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>        
#1         1    NA     5     2    NA 09:01:07.2123
#2         2     1     4     4     1 09:03:02.6145
#3         3     3     3     1     5 10:12:01.3435
#4         4    NA    NA     1     2 12:07:13.1187
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(StudentId = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), Q1 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA), Q2 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA), 
Q3 = c(2L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Q4 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 
5L, NA, 2L), SystemTime = c("09:01:07.2123", "09:03:01.3145", 
"09:03:02.6145", "09:47:17.6541", "10:01:17.2343", "10:12:01.3435", 
"12:07:13.1187")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: is it possible not to hard code the column name 'Q'. I am specifically refering to this line `fill(starts_with('Q')) `. My real dataset has many columns and they are not labeled Q. They can be anything

Comment: you can `fill` by position : `df %>% 
  group_by(StudentId) %>%
  fill(2:5)` Or `fill` everything except group column `df %>% 
  group_by(StudentId) %>%
  fill(-group_cols())`

Comment: should i specify .direction = "up" or "down" ? in the fill function ?

Comment: The default direction is "down" which suits your description i.e `impute the missing data in the most recent response based on that student (StudentID) previous response.`. so you don't need to add anything here. Other options are `direction = 'up'` or `'updown'`

Comment: arrange the df by time then do group_by first >?

Comment: Yes, that approach can be used as well but need to add additional `arrange`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer makes no assumptions about the column names.

```
df = read_csv("StudentId,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,SystemTime
1,,5,2,,09:01:07.2123
2,1,4,4,,09:03:01.3145
2,,4,4,1,09:03:02.6145
3,1,3,,2,09:47:17.6541
3,1,,,5,10:01:17.2343
3,3,,1,,10:12:01.3435
4,,,1,2,12:07:13.1187")


# A tibble: 7 x 6
  StudentId    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4 SystemTime
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <time>    
1         1    NA     5     2    NA 09:01:07  
2         2     1     4     4    NA 09:03:01  
3         2    NA     4     4     1 09:03:02  
4         3     1     3    NA     2 09:47:17  
5         3     1    NA    NA     5 10:01:17  
6         3     3    NA     1    NA 10:12:01  
7         4    NA    NA     1     2 12:07:13
```

Use `group_by`

```
df %>% group_by(StudentId) %>% 
  arrange(SystemTime) %>%
  summarise_all(~ last(na.omit(.)))


# A tibble: 4 x 6
  StudentId    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4 SystemTime
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <time>    
1         1    NA     5     2    NA 09:01:07  
2         2     1     4     4     1 09:03:02  
3         3     3     3     1     5 10:12:01  
4         4    NA    NA     1     2 12:07:13
```

Comment: Thanks David. I will try that. This seems more efficient with just 2 lines.

Comment: Although, this works for the example shared it does not consider `SystemTime` at all. It will fail if there are two non-NA values in a group and the first one has a higher `SystemTime`.

Comment: The example data was in chronological order; I took that as a given.  I've edited my response, adding an `arrange`, so that guaranteed.  I also assume that `SystemTime` won't be NA.  But if I understand the problem statement, the student's last non-NA value for each question is what's wanted. @ronak-shah I'm not sure I'm understanding your objection.